# Error retrieving data from api call as attribute is different

Tags: json, api, vue.js, axios

Hi there I'm using a api which returns as follows

```
{"secret-finance":{"usd":0.04883396}}
```

Problem is I'm using vue and retrieving data like this

```
async getCurrentSefiPrice() {
  await axios
    .get(
      "https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/simple/price?ids=secret-finance&vs_currencies=usd"
    )
    .then(
      (response) =>
        (this.sefi_token_current_price = response.secret-finance.usd)
      // console.log(response)
    );
  console.log(this.sefi_token_current_price);
}
```

But when I use `secret-finance` to get usd value I get an error.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@haseebsaeed
You'll need to reference it as

```
response["secret-finance"].usd
```

You need to use key notation rather then dot notion when a key has a hyphen in it. Any key that contains characters that are not allowed in JavaScript variables you'll need to reference them as above.

A further example,
If the `secret-finance` object has a property key of `us-dollars` rather than the current one of `usd`, you would then access it by doing,

```
response["secret-finance"]["us-dollars"]
```